# MySQL query - find "new" users per day

Tags: mysql, aggregate

I have a table of data with the following fields

```
EventID        : Int, AutoIncrement, Primary Key
EventType      : Int                             ' Defines what happened
EventTimeStamp : DateTime                        ' When the Event Happened
UserID         : Int                             ' Unique
```

The query needs to tell me how many events occurred with new UserIDs for each day in the whole set. So, for each day, how many events exist which have a UserID which doesn't exist in any prior day. I've tried lots, and I can get unique users per day, but can't work out how to get 'NEW' users per day.

Comment: Can we assume that UserID is **not** unique in your events table?

Comment: Yes, sorry, that is the case.

Comment: Also, I seem to have been unclear. What I need is the number of new users per day - not the amount of activity for new users per day - if that makes sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you all for your help - I've voted up the assistance. Here's what I did:

I created these 2 views (I needed to end up with a view, and had to create 2 as it seems you can't nest select statements within views).

Sightings:

```
select min(to_days(`Events`.TimeStamp)) AS Day0,
    `Events`.TimeStamp AS TimeStamp,
    `Events`.UserID AS UserID
from `Events` group by `Events`.UserID order by `Events`.UserID
```

NewUsers:

```
select count(distinct Sightings.UserID) AS Count,
    date(Sightings.TimeStamp) AS Date from Sightings
    group by date(Sightings.TimeStamp)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Select count(EventId) from table
where 
UserId 
  not in (select UserId from table where EventTimeStamp < now() - interval 1 day)
```

Answer (score 1):

Good question. I don't have an exact solution but here's the approach I've seen before:

Do a SELECT where you compare the `EventTimeStamp` with `MIN(EventTimeStamp)` for a given userID, as determined by a nested SELECT statement on the same table to calculate the MIN timestamp for each ID (e.g. `GROUP BY UserID`).

Answer (score 1):

First get a table `b` with for each user when he first arrived,
then join that table to get all events for that user for that day.

```
SELECT DATE(a.EventTimeStamp), COUNT(*) FROM table a
JOIN
(SELECT MIN(EventTimeStamp) AS EventTimeStamp, UserID from table group by userID) b
ON a.UserID = b.UserID
AND DATE(a.EventTimeStamp) = DATE(b.EventTimeStamp) 
GROUP BY DATE(a.EventTimeStamp)
```

Answer (score -1):

86400-(EventTimeStamp) as new_users

Comment: Not sure I understand this answer - what am I missing?