# mysql: get new users per day, and cumulative total users by day

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have a mysql table t:

```
DateTime timestamp;
int userid;
```

and I want to know how many total users I have over time.  I have this:

```
2012-12-04 102
2012-12-05 101
2012-12-05 102
2012-12-05 103
2012-12-07 101
2012-12-08 104
```

So the first time 101 is seen is 12/5, the first time 104 is seen is 12/7, and so on.  So I'd like this, for total-users-ever-seen by date:

```
2012-12-04 1
2012-12-05 3
2012-12-07 3
2012-12-08 4
```

(I don't care if there are extra dates in there with no new entries.)

The closest I've been able to get is the number of new users per day:

```
select distinct date, count(*) from 
 (select MIN(DATE(timestamp)) date from t group by userid order by date) t1 \
GROUP BY date;
```

which seems to work; the subquery gives the earliest timestamp for each userid, and the outer query combines by date.  But how can I roll that up to get the total ever seen?

Oh yeah, I looked at [MySQL query - find "new" users per day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422827/mysql-query-find-new-users-per-day) but it didn't seem to do what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT x.timestamp
     , COUNT(DISTINCT y.userid)
  FROM t x
  JOIN t y
    ON y.timestamp <= x.timestamp
 GROUP
    BY timestamp;
```

GaryO, to understand why this works, just rewrite it this way...

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.timestamp, y.userid
  FROM t x
  JOIN t y
    ON y.timestamp <= x.timestamp
 ORDER
    BY x.timestamp
     , y.userid;
```

Using sgeddes's sqlfiddle, this gives us the following intermediate result:

```
+---------------------+--------+
| timestamp           | userid |
+---------------------+--------+
| 2012-12-04 00:00:00 |    102 |
| 2012-12-05 00:00:00 |    101 |
| 2012-12-05 00:00:00 |    102 |
| 2012-12-05 00:00:00 |    103 |
| 2012-12-07 00:00:00 |    101 |
| 2012-12-07 00:00:00 |    102 |
| 2012-12-07 00:00:00 |    103 |
| 2012-12-08 00:00:00 |    101 |
| 2012-12-08 00:00:00 |    102 |
| 2012-12-08 00:00:00 |    103 |
| 2012-12-08 00:00:00 |    104 |
+---------------------+--------+
```

So in the final query, all we've done is COUNT this result when grouped by date.

Comment: Code only answers are almost as bad as link only answers. They're not really answers at all. A good answer contains explanations and reasoning and possibly some sources or authority.

Comment: Looks like you've got a busy day ahead of you markus! This solution has the advantage over the only other answer thus far provided of being correct.

Comment: Explain why your answer is correct, downvote the other answer and explain why it isn't correct. That's how SO works... that's what makes SO not-a-forum!

Comment: My answer's superficially correct because it provides a result that corresponds to the one the OP desired. If the OP - or anyone else - desires more explanation, they're welcome, even encouraged, to ask, politely, and I'll try to help. But I do not like being told what to do.

Comment: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully.aspx

Comment: Although I'd love to understand more about why this works, it does work.  It gives the dates and total number of users seen to date (as of that date) in each row of the output.

Comment: Thanks for the update -- now I get it!  (I can also see that it's quadratic, which is fine for me, but good to know.)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand your requirements, you are looking to return the date and the count of users that they first appeared?

```
SELECT TimeStamp, COUNT(*) 
FROM T JOIN (
   SELECT MIN(TimeStamp) minDate, UserId
   FROM t 
   GROUP BY UserId) T2 ON T.TimeStamp = T2.minDate AnD T.UserId = T2.UserId
GROUP BY T.TimeStamp
```

And the Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c1f5a/9

Good luck.

Comment: sqlfiddle is cool!  That alone is worth knowing!  But what I was hoping for was a running total of how many users are in the system, by date.  Strawberry's answer below is what I'm looking for.  I tested that answer using your sqlfiddle though -- thanks!